# Declaring Variables in Objective C similar to Java

Tags: java, objective-c

In java, you can define variables by adding an existing variable to the condition.

```
String hi = "he";
String hello = hi + "llo";
```

Is something like this possible to do in Objective c? If not exactly like this, are there any other ways to achieve a similar goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Initialise them in `-init`, AFAIK that's the first chance to initialise instance variables.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where that is. I am a beginner at Objective c. And I don't understand most syntax. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: NSString *hello = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", hi, @"llo"];

Comment: @user2609670 Forget my previous comment. It makes no sense as I misread the question. Happens to me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For objects, no; the `+` operator cannot be overridden in Objective-C as it is in Java for strings. You'd do something like this instead:

```
NSString *hi = @"he";
NSString *hello = [hi stringByAppendingString:@"llo"];
// (Or one of the many other NSString methods for creating new strings)
```

You can, of course, do this for C primitive types, like `ints`:

```
int x = 10;
int y = x + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     NSMutableString *str= [[NSMutableString alloc ]initWithCapacity:3];
    [str appendString:@"he"];
    [str appendString:@"llo"];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: Thank you but, I am trying to get an already declared and defined String to declare my variable.

Comment: Ok then use `stringByAppendingString:` method